# Why does python script works differently in Spyder vs cmd prompt

Tags: python, cmd, spyder, pathlib

I have the following script **test.py**:

```
import pathlib, os

path = "C:\\Windows"
pathparent = pathlib.Path("C:\\Windows").parent

if os.path.exists(pathparent):
    print("path exists")
```

and when I execute it in Spyder IDE I get this:

```
path exists
```

when I run it from the command prompt (**python test.py**) I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    if os.path.exists(pathparent):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py", line 19, in exists
    os.stat(path)
TypeError: argument should be string, bytes or integer, not WindowsPath
```

Any idea why I get the different results?

Note: I know that wrapping **pathparent** in **str()** will make the **if** statement succeed, but what I want to know is why the the two environments yield different results.

Comment: Are spider and your prompt using different versions of python?

Comment: That's interesting, I added print(sys.version) and got "3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]" in Spyder and "3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 07:26:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]" at the command prompt.

Comment: try running both using v3.6.0 and see if the error persists

Comment: I updated it and that fixed it - thanks!  I'm still trying to sort out Anaconda, Spyder, and python and who's installing what and how they're all related/updated, but that's for another day - I'm glad to know why I was getting strange results.

Comment: Also, I just did a search on os.path.exists() and this is what the docs say:

Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a path-like object.

That answers that!

Comment: great, I've added an answer which summarizes that so we can mark this question as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.path.exists()` started accepting path objects in Python 3.6 and your problem is occuring in your cmd prompts as it is running Python 3.5, change it to 3.6 to fix your problem.